# XML to JSON Conversion not working as expected in OIC gen 2

Tags: json, xml, oracle-integration-cloud

XML to JSON Conversion not working as expected in OIC gen 2

I have a JSON as below:

```
[{
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceOCMKey",
        "value": "CONT02188B7945234A579D133040C0137BA2"
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceOCMURL",
        "value": "https://vertivocmdev-vertiv.cec.ocp.oraclecloud.com/content/published/api/v1.1/assets/CONT02188B7945234A579D133040C0137BA2/native/pinksky.jpeg?channelToken=16b0852b8932439693348f2bfedb0562"
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceLanguages",
        "value": [
            "en"
        ]
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceCountry",
        "value": [
            "USA",
            "Italy"
        ]
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceOCMVersion",
        "value": "1.0"
    }
]
```

so when i am giving this json as sample request the backend xsd is making **value** as a repeating tag with maxOccurs=unbounded and because of that when the XML to JSON Conversion is happening it is considering all Value to be an Array and the output looks something like this:

```
[{
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceOCMKey",
        "value":[ "CONT02188B7945234A579D133040C0137BA2"]
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceOCMURL",
        "value": ["https://vertivocmdev-vertiv.cec.ocp.oraclecloud.com/content/published/api/v1.1/assets/CONT02188B7945234A579D133040C0137BA2/native/pinksky.jpeg?channelToken=16b0852b8932439693348f2bfedb0562"]
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceLanguages",
        "value": [
            "en"
        ]
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceCountry",
        "value": [
            "USA",
            "Italy"
        ]
    },
    {
        "fieldTypeId": "ResourceOCMVersion",
        "value":[ "1.0"]
    }
]
```

I want that if the value has only single iteration treat it like string otherwise as array

Trying to convert XML to JSON in OIC Gen2